# Random Apache 403 Errors

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

I am getting random 403 errors on my local machine. I will be viewing my local site, everything working just fine, then I will refresh the page and it will throw a 403 error. If I restart apache everything works for a period of time and then all of a sudden when loading the same page I will get the 403 error and must restart Apache.

I'm not sure where to being looking into this. I have set `Required all granted` on the directory and the permissions are set to `drwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: https://superuser.com/questions/787888/too-many-files-open-on-mac-osx-after-running-apache-in-php-with-xdebug-for-som The accepted answer shows there is a bug with Xdebug on OSX: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1070

I also had in php.ini xdebug.remote_autostart = 1, I have disabled this as recommended